# Servlet not getting intialised after springboot migrated to 3.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets

Migrated to springboot 3.1.0.

I have a Soap configuration class like below to map the url which uses 'WSSpringServlet' and it is giving compile error after the upgrade.

../SoapConfiguration.java:30: error: type argument WSSpringServlet is not within bounds of type-variable T
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
^
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Servlet declared in class ServletRegistrationBean
../SoapConfiguration.java:32: error: cannot infer type arguments for ServletRegistrationBean<>
ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new WSSpringServlet(), OFFER_ENDPOINT);

Below is my SoapConfiguration.java:

```
package com.mydump.esb.offer.config;

import org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.SpringBinding;
import com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet;

import com.mydump.esb.offer.components.OfferEndpoint;


@Configuration
public class SoapConfiguration {

    private static final String OFFER_ENDPOINT = "/customer/soap/offer/v1";

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<WSSpringServlet> servletRegistrationBean() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new WSSpringServlet(), OFFER_ENDPOINT);
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringBinding bindLocalityEndpoint(@Autowired OfferEndpoint endpoint) throws Exception {
        return bind(endpoint, OFFER_ENDPOINT);
    }

    private SpringBinding bind(OfferEndpoint endpoint, String url) throws Exception {
        SpringService springService = new SpringService();
        springService.setBean(endpoint);
        SpringBinding binding = new SpringBinding();
        binding.setService(springService.getObject());
        binding.setUrl(url);
        return binding;
    }
}
```

What should I use in place of WSSpringServlet in Springboot 3.1.0 ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, were you able to find any solutions?